# GMSMarker infoWindow not updating

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uiviewcontroller, google-maps-markers

I'm using Google map and it's marker. For displaying information on the marker I'm using custom View to display it. But values are not updating once I init it.
Below is my code for that.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView!, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: marker.position.latitude, longitude: marker.position.longitude
        var markerView : MarkerInfoView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MarkerInfoView", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! MarkerInfoView
        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarkers, error) in
            if let placemarker = placemarkers?.last {
                var strAddress = ""
                if let str = placemarker.name {
                    strAddress += str
                }
                if let str = placemarker.subAdministrativeArea {
                    strAddress += ", " + str
                }
                print(strAddress)
                markerView.deviceInfo.text = "HELLO TESTING"
            print(markerView.deviceInfo.text!) // This is printing "HELLO TESTING", but not updating on marker
                markerView.addressInfo.text = strAddress
            }
        }
        if let str = marker.snippet {
            markerView.deviceInfo.text = str.components(separatedBy: "|")[0]
            //TODO: add time
            markerView.dateInfo.text = str.components(separatedBy: "|")[1]
//            markerView.addressInfo.text = ""
        }
        else {
            markerView.deviceInfo.text = ""
            markerView.dateInfo.text = ""
//            markerView.addressInfo.text = ""
        }
        return markerView

    }
```

Please guide me how to update values in infoWindow.

Comment: Are you called mapView.delegate = self

Comment: yes, I've set delegate @iOS

Comment: Actually marker.title = "This can print text", but you are using "markerView.deviceInfo.text"  I think this is custom label. where you created this label

Comment: I've customView, in that I'm displaying those information like deviceName, dateInfo and addressInfo. Already added code how I'm creating that custom view in "var markerView : MarkerInfoView ...." line

Comment: Me, also used custom view to display content, but I used func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoContents marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? { } function. With in this function I created my labels, so labels will be created each time and that can display content. I'm not created this labels globally. If you want I can post my code

Comment: Sure, maybe that can solve my problem

Comment: Hay, try my code, make changes based on your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
// MARKER - GoogleMaps delegate
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoContents marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
    print("title \(markerTitle)")

    var infoView:UIView!

    infoView = UIView()
    infoView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 75)
    infoView.backgroundColor = .black

    let orderIDLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 75))
    orderIDLbl.text = "markerTitle" //Your title here
    orderIDLbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    orderIDLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    orderIDLbl.numberOfLines = 0
    orderIDLbl.textColor = .white
    infoView.addSubview(orderIDLbl)

    return infoView
}
```

Comment: If you want for loop use it, other wise remove it. And create labels based on your requirements.

Comment: My code making async requesting so the view will return before response arrives and when the response arrives view is not going to update those values